# Opposite of Absorbing State

Tags: calculus, markov-process

This should be fairly standard, but I fail to google it, and nothing on the matter is on Math.SE.

How do we call the opposite of an absorbing state? If we think about Markov chains/systems, that would be a state such that there is no positive transition probability to that state from any other one.

In other words, a state that - if we didn't start in it - we would never end up in it.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard term for such a thing, but a word that is used in similar contexts (usually as opposed to "attractive") is "repelling"

Comment: In terms of flow diagrams, absorbing states are called "sinks" and the state you describe are called "sources".

Answer (score 2):

In the context of finite state automata, such states are called [Garden of Eden states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_of_Eden_(cellular_automaton)).

E.F. Moore proved existence of such states of certain infinite automata in *Machine models of self-reproduction*, **Proc. Sympos. Appl. Math.**, Vol. 14, pp. 17-34 (1963).  See [Amorosa and Cooper (1970)](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-026-01/S0002-9939-1970-0276007-5/home.html) for some extensions to finite configurations.

Moore attributed the name to John Tukey in the 1950's.